Could not resolve project :opensdk in VCamera
I am trying to build this project, I fixed some errors but now I am getting this error:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :opensdk.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :opensdk was found. The consumer was configured to find a component for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.1.0', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 159ms

from files>settings>search 'Android sdk' I installed Android 13.0 Platform with API level 33, Android SDK command line tools (latest).
but I'm still getting that error. I sync the files, gradle clean, and gradle build, but the same happens.
I updated build.gradle in root directory like this:
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.8.22"
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.0"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andvipgroup/CameraLib/master" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    minSdkVersion = 24
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
    javaVersion = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    abiFilters = "armeabi-v7a,arm64-v8a"
    localTest = false
    isMasterPkg = true
    hackJarName = "hack.jar"
    versionCode = 100
    versionName = "1.0.0"
    masterPkg = "virtual.camera.app"
    assistPkg = "virtual.camera.app.assist"
}

build.gradle in :app module like this:
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    namespace "virtual.camera.app"
    compileSdk rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId rootProject.ext.masterPkg
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode rootProject.ext.versionCode
        versionName rootProject.ext.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
        maxProcessCount 8
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    aaptOptions {
        cruncherEnabled = false
        useNewCruncher = false
    }

    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        warningsAsErrors false
        disable "UnusedResources", 'RestrictedApi'
        textOutput "stdout"
        textReport false
        check 'NewApi', 'InlinedApi'
    }
}

tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
    options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
    options.addStringOption('encoding', 'UTF-8')
    options.addStringOption('charSet', 'UTF-8')
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar", "*.aar"])

    //android
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-rc01'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0"
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.3"
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation 'com.tbuonomo:dotsindicator:4.2'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:input:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.nukc.stateview:kotlin:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.roger.catloadinglibrary:catloadinglibrary:1.0.9'
    implementation 'com.github.Ferfalk:SimpleSearchView:0.2.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Othershe:CornerLabelView:1.0.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.11'
    implementation 'com.gitee.cbfg5210:RVAdapter:0.3.7'
    implementation 'com.imuxuan:floatingview:1.6'

    implementation project(':opensdk')
    implementation 'virtual.camera.camera:camera:1.0.0'
}

gradle-wrapper.properties like this:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2-bin.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

settings.gradle :
include ':app'
include ':opensdk'

rootProject.name = "VCamera"

Any help is appreciated.
